# MIPS - How to compute sum of the array

Tags: arrays, mips, mips32, mars-simulator, mips64

i have this MIPS program that lets the user to input 10 integers and this program should be able to compute and display its sum.

```
.data    
    array: .space 40        
    input: .asciiz      "Enter the 10 Elements: \n"    
    output: .asciiz     "\nThe sum is: "  
 
.text 
main:
    la $a0, input          # Loads address of 'input' to print
    li $v0, 4           # System call code for printing string
    syscall             # Prints string
    
    jal loop            # Jumps and links to 'loop' label
    li $v0, 10    
        syscall         # System call to exit program
     
loop:    
    beq $t0, 40, end         
        li $v0, 5           # System call code for reading integer
        syscall         # Reads the integer
       
        sw $v0, array($t0)      # Store word, store the values in RAM. $t0 is the index
        add $t0, $t0, 4     

        j loop          # Jumps to loop label
           
end:     
        la $a0, output      # Loads address of 'output' to print
        li $v0, 4       # System call code for printing string
        syscall         # Prints string
        
        add $a0, $zero, $t1  
        li  $v0, 1          # System call code for printing integer
        syscall             # Prints the sum
        
        jr $ra          # Returns the value
```

although, my problem is that it doesn't display its sum but rather just 0 in the output:

```
Enter the 10 Elements: 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

The sum is: 0
```

Whereas, it should be displaying the sum of all integers inputted by the user:

```
Enter the 10 Elements: 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

The sum is: 55
```

Is the problem on the *loop* label? Or the way I store the numbers in the array?

I don't get it how the sum displays 0.

I'm still getting into MIPS Assembly Language so it would be very helpful to point out where I did it wrong. And any suggestions in improving the way I write my code in MIPS? Thank you.

Comment: _"I don't get it how the sum displays 0."_  Because you're printing the value of `$t1` (because of `add $a0, $zero, $t1`). And you're never writing to `$t1` in your code, so presumably it has its initial value of 0.

Comment: Side note: storing the values into an array is pointless if all you want to do is sum them up. Just add the values directly to some register that you initialize to 0 before the loop.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn debugging.  Debugging machine code and assembly  is just like debugging any other language in that you single step each line and validate the the program did what it is supposed to do for that line of code.